# Cannot see dropdown shortcut to site dashboard in WordPress network why?

Tags: multisite, admin-bar

As per title and following screenshot
[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your user are not inside the user-list of each blog in network active; maybe you are Super-Admin. Go to 'Sites (All Sites)' --> Edit a blog in Sites --> Tab 'Users' --> Add your user to the list of users and see the dropdown.